# How to solve Unable to load CSS and JS after setup magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, file-permissions, ubuntu

[image]

My using Ubuntu 18 and apache2

**I downloaded magento2 zip file and extract**

uploaded to my /var/www/html/

but always shows the above image

I already setup

htaccess file

Already tried comments:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-condent:deploy -f
```

cleared cache and still not working home page also

How i can solve **Unable to load CSS and JS**

Answer (score 0):

Give the full permission of pub and var folder.

Comment: I already use comment 

sudo chmod -R 777 var/www/html/myproject


but not working

Comment: Check the path of your CSS and js file. Or Also check you're in database based URL end with "/".

Comment: which table i can check the css and js file path

Comment: core_config_data table check web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url.

Comment: core_config_data  table i set two rows

localhost/myproject/index.php/

and 

localhost/myproject/index.php/

already has this

Comment: In the browser network tab, checks css path.

Comment: after checking css path what i do

Comment: Path is correct or not check. If it's is display 404 then somewhere you use the wrong url.

Comment: thank you if is not working how i can contact

Comment: Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/test/index.php/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs/require.js”

Comment: you can contact me on my email id  easyndfaster@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

setting icons

1 : need to give full permissions to public_html
    {chmod 777 -R .}

2 : static content deploy comnd
    {php bin/magento s:s:d -f}

3 : need to make extension of apache a2enmod rewriteable using 
     {sudo a2enmod rewrite}

4 : now give www permission to all by using 
    {sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf}

5 : now restart apache
    {sudo service apache2 restart}

Comment: is this helpful?

Comment: (4) how to give www permission to etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: i tried not working.......

any other way

Comment: 1 : static content deploy comnd {php bin/magento s:s:d -f}
2:upgrade { php bin/magento setup:upgrade}
2: clean cache { php bin/magento cache:clean}
3: now restart apache {sudo service apache2 restart}


try this one

Comment: 4 : now give www permission to all by using {sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf}   you can run this command any where this for giving permision for user and groups but normally is it already done by system

Comment: i gived but not loading js and css files

Comment: then it can be other issue rather then CSS and JS files.....